# How to create connectors to the edge of boxes in raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'd like to have the connectors go only to the edges of the boxes, not to the center as they do now. I can fake it, graphically, by putting the connectors behind the boxes, but I'd like the arrow ends to be visible at the edge of the boxes.

```
    connection.view = paper.path(
        'M'+connection.from.x+','+connection.from.y+' '+
        'L'+connection.to.x+','+connection.to.y
    ).attr({
            'stroke-width':5,
            'stroke': 'blue',
            'arrow-end': 'block-midium-midium',
            'arrow-start': 'oval-narrow-short'});;
```

I can't seem to find anything in the Raphael doco to say how this could be done.
I have a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/21cp7q3d/

Answer (score 1):

```
connection.view = paper.path(
        'M'+(connection.from.x + w / 2)+','+connection.from.y+' '+
        'L'+connection.to.x+','+connection.to.y
    )
```

just modify de x or y do half of the size of the box.

or you might add where you want to start in you box.

```
{x:100,y:100,start:150,title:'LTM',color:'lightgray'}

connection.view = paper.path(
        'M'+connection.from.start+','+connection.from.y+' '+
        'L'+connection.to.x+','+connection.to.y
    )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/21cp7q3d/1/

then do the opposite

```
connection.view = paper.path(
        'M'+connection.from.x+','+connection.from.y+' '+
        'L'+(connection.to.x - w / 2)+','+connection.to.y
    )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/21cp7q3d/2/

Comment: Thats not exactly what I was after. That moves the connection point to the edge, I was trying to keep the center of the box as the target point, but the connector terminating at the edge.

Comment: that still puts the connectors over the top of the boxes when they are moved and the origin of the connectors are the corners, not the center

Answer (score 0):

Check This Out this is Old Code of mine, may be it will help you out somehow.

[More than 4 connecting points in graffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148073/how-to-modify-raphael-graffle-example-to-support-more-than-4-connecting-points)